# MainActivity unresolved class error with android studio

Tags: android

Im taking the udacity coarse and for some reason android studio wont recognize my MainActivity class. Ive tried cleaning the project, rebuilding and making sure that the names were correct but nothing has solved my problem.

Android Manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="androidedx.example.activitylifecycle">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Activity1"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, is this your manifest file's code? Because <application> tag must be a direct child of <manifest> tag.

Comment: @MohammedSiddiq yeah, so should I just make another project and only paste the second half of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, this package name within the code I had to paste

```
package com.example.android.cookies;
```

Im not sure why specifically this caused the problem but atleast I solved it.